# Getting exception while using C++ dll in VB.Net

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, exception, interop

I have created unmanaged dll and used in VB.Net.

Both code snippiest is as follows.

VB.Net

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim c As cls = New cls()
        c.Start()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class cls
    Declare Sub Only Lib "dllproj2.dll" Alias "Only" (b As StringBuilder)

    Public Sub Start()
        Dim s As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(15)

        Only(s) '**Actual call to dll code **
        Dim s1 As String = s.ToString.ToLower
        Dim len As Integer = s.ToString.Length.ToString()
        Console.Write(s.ToString())
    End Sub

End Class
```

C++ dll

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstring>

extern "C"{
void Only(char *a)
{
    char arr[10];

    printf("Reached");
    sprintf(arr,"This %d",33);
    printf("\n%s\n",arr);
    memcpy(a,arr,10);

}
}
```

Now as soon as I access line  `Only(s)` I get exception shown in image.

[image]

I am not able to understand cause of exception. Output of code is fine, but while running it using Visual Studio 2012 Express it is giving above error.

It is sample code, which we also used in production, I afraid it may cause problem in future.

Kindly suggest is there any way to get rid of exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `b`as:   `UnmanagedType.LPStr`

```
Declare Sub Only Lib "dllproj2.dll" Alias "Only" (<InAttribute(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> b As StringBuilder)
```

Comment: But b is getting modified in C++ code, so InAttribute() is OK? And I tried suggested, still getting same exception..

Comment: InAttribute indicates that data should be marshaled from the caller to the callee, but not back to the caller.

Comment: OK I understand, but when I use suggested code I still getting exception.

Comment: Same as I posted in question (image)

Comment: Have you executed your Only method?? Is is working ok without exceptions?. Extract it to a void main to check it is working. The signature seems ok now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39465/discussion-between-pranitkothari-and-carlos-landeras)